# What's the fastest way to get the partial value of a number in C#?

Tags: c#, floating-point

```
float f = 5.13;
double d = 5.13;

float fp = f - (float)Math.floor(f);
double dp = d - Math.floor(d);
```

Isn't there any faster way than calling an external function every time?

Comment: you mean faster as in performance?

Comment: In order to break your current set of bad habits, you should really start thinking CONSTANTLY of how bad it is to optimize.  Every character you type right now  you should be thinking "How readable is this going to be" instead.  You really have no idea if the Math. routines are even being called or compiled inline--if you come up with an algebraic in-line solution, there is a REALLY GOOD chance it will be slower.  Just stop thinking about performance, please.

Comment: I've been waiting for someone to point out that his code gives the WRONG answer at least some of the time (such as in his example, f = 5.13f). float fp = f - (float) Math.floor(f) results in 0.1300001

Comment: @Martin: According to labls.developerfusion.co.uk and koders.com, FCallFloor converts the decimal to a string and then truncates the part after the dot.  Clearly you can get a much better result if you write your own unmanaged call which converts the decimal to a string and then truncates the part before the dot.  This avoids a subtraction, so it's much better! The next step is to use an asm lookup table so that you can parse more than one character at a time.  That strategy is sometimes mentioned for use in crazy-fast optimizations in certain high performance graphics libraries.

Comment: @Grant: That's the price of working with floats.  IIRC, Decimals don't have that problem since they use base 10 internally.  But they have performance problems instead, of course.

Comment: @Brian: My point is that it doesn't matter how fast something is if it gives incorrect results. If all someone cares about is speed, they should 'optimize' every long-running method that returns a numeric value with 'return (new Random()).Next();', or 'return 4'; ... Bill K is correct, people need to stop thinking so much about performance and think more about what is readable, and CORRECT.

Comment: @Grant: My response to Martin gives a faster algorithm that is also just as accurate.  It's also way overkill for most purposes.

Comment: @Grant - by that logic, does, "Decimal a = 1; Decimal b = 3; Decimal C = a/b; generate an incorrect result since you can't represent 1/3 in decimal with limited digits?

Comment: @Michael: No, his logic would not consider that answer to be correct.  Grant's argument is that you are losing accuracy because when you use Math.floor, you end up casting to a different base, and back again.  a/b cannot, using decimal, be represented accurately at all.  0.13 can be represented accurately using decimal.  Now, if you instead said Decimal C = (a/b) * b, you might have a point.  But considering that manixrock is only asking for an fpart operation, which can be done accurately, it wouldn't be a very strong point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could cast f to an int which would trim the fractional part.  This presumes that your doubles fall within the range of an integer.

Of course, the jitter may be smart enough to optimize Math.floor to some inlined asm that'll do the floor, which may be faster than the cast to int then cast back to float.

Have you actually measured and verified that the performance of Math.floor is affecting your program?  If you haven't, you shouldn't bother with this level of micro-optimization until you know that is a problem, and then measure the performance of this alternative against the original code.

EDIT:  This does appear faster.  The following code takes 717ms when using Math.Floor(), and 172 ms for the int casting code on my machine, in release mode.  But again, I doubt the perf improvement really matters - to get this to be measurable I had to do 100m iterations.  Also, I find Math.Floor() to be much more readable and obvious what the intent is, and a future CLR could emit more optimal code for Math.Floor and beat out this approach easily.

```
    private static double Floor1Test()
    {
        // Keep track of results in total so ops aren't optimized away.
        double total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
        {
            float f = 5.13f;
            double d = 5.13;
            float fp = f - (float)Math.Floor(f);
            double dp = d - (float)Math.Floor(d);
            total = fp + dp;
        }

        return total;
    }

    private static double Floor2Test()
    {
        // Keep track of total so ops aren't optimized away.
        double total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
        {
            float f = 5.13f;
            double d = 5.13;
            float fp = f - (int)(f);
            double dp = d - (int)(d);
            total = fp + dp;
        }

        return total;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch timer = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

        // Unused run first, guarantee code is JIT'd.
        timer.Start();
        Floor1Test();
        Floor2Test();
        timer.Stop();

        timer.Reset();
        timer.Start();
        Floor1Test();
        timer.Stop();
        long floor1time = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        timer.Reset();
        timer.Start();
        Floor2Test();
        timer.Stop();

        long floor2time = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        Console.WriteLine("Floor 1 - {0} ms", floor1time);
        Console.WriteLine("Floor 2 - {0} ms", floor2time);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's theoretically possible for your two approaches to get different results.  As a result, it is possible that, even if the people writing the CLR consider the optimization you describe, they may reject it due to weird issues that most (but not all) people don't care about.

Comment: float fp = f - (int)(f) gives the wrong answer at least some of the time, such as when f = 5.13f.

Comment: @Brian - Sure, I just wanted to call out that just because the current code-gen for Math.Floor is sub-par, it could easily be improved in the future.

Comment: @Grant - I prefer "less-precise" than wrong when dealing with floating point like this :)  Mapping floats to base-ten integers always has precision issues.

Comment: @Grant: float fp = f - (int)(f) is not giving a wrong answer.  Floats are in base 2.  You are assuming 5.13f means 5.13M, but it does not.  That a normal user assumes it will is the user's mistake.  If the user expected to be working with a floating point decimal number, they'd be using decimal.

Comment: I added a 3rd function for only the loop itself to remove the time it takes for the other loop elements, and got these results (Release version): Loops - 34 ms, Floor 1 - 620 ms, Floor 2 - 197 ms. So it clearly shows that the int method is 3.14 times faster.

Comment: Casting to int doesn't work if the double is outside the range of int.

Comment: @Eric - Updated answer.  I thought about it, but guessed noone would notice :)

Answer (score 5):

"External function"?

System.Math is built into mscorlib!

This is actually the fastest way to do this.

Comment: @MiffTheFox: No it isn't.  My answer is faster...and just as clear.  :P

Comment: @Michael: I suspect yours is faster than mine, but feel no urge to check.  But yours works with floats, too.  And is still relatively clear.

Answer (score 3):

Donald E. Knuth said:

> "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature
>   optimization is the root of all evil."

So unless you have benchmarked your application and found positive evidence that this operations is the bottleneck, then don't bother optimizing these this line of code.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I doubt you'll get any real world performance gain, but according to Reflector Math.Floor is this:

```
public static decimal Floor(decimal d)
{
    return decimal.Floor(d);
}
```

So arguably

```
double dp = d - decimal.Floor(d);
```

may be quicker. (Compiler optimisations make the whole point moot I know...)

---

For those who may be interested to take this to its logical conclusion decimal.Floor is:

```
public static decimal Floor(decimal d)
{
    decimal result = 0M;
    FCallFloor(ref result, d);
    return result;
}
```

with FCallFloor being a invoke to unmanaged code, so you are pretty much at the limit of the "optimisation" there.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of `Decimal`, I would recommend ignoring everyone yelling not to change it and try using `Decimal.Truncate`.  Whether it is faster or not, it *is* a function specifically intended for what you are trying to do and thus is a bit clearer.

Oh, and by the way, it is faster:

```
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch foo = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

        Decimal x = 1.5M;
        Decimal y = 1;
        int tests = 1000000;
        foo.Start();
        for (int z = 0; z < tests; ++z)
        {
            y = x - Decimal.Truncate(x);
        }
        foo.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(foo.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        foo.Reset();
        foo.Start();
        for (int z = 0; z < tests; ++z)
        {
            y = x - Math.Floor(x);
        }
        foo.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(foo.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.ReadKey();

//Output: 123
//Output: 164
```

Edit: Fixed my explanation and code.

Comment: Yes, the querent said his issue was calling an external function.  But I automatically ignored that in favor of what seemed to me to be the more obvious issue.

Comment: Doesn't Decimal.Truncate() return the integral digits? his solution returns the fractional portion. To get the result in wants, I think you need y = x - Decimal.Truncate(x);

Comment: @Grant: Yeah, I wasn't paying attention.  It's still faster, though.

Comment: @After x - Decimal.Truncate(x) fix: I get ~125/100 timing in my tests using your code. But I think that ignores the real issue. x - Decimal.Truncate(x); gives you the CORRECT answer all the time. x - (float) Math.floor(x); gives you the WRONG answer at least some of the time (such as when x = 5.13f).

Comment: That is because Truncate works in base 10 whereas Floor works in base 2.

Answer (score 0):

It is static so this should be really fast, there is no object to stand up.  You can always to bit level math, but unless you have some serious use the function.  Likely the floor() method is already doing this, but you could inline it and cut out checks etc if you need something really fast, but in C# this is not your greatest performance issue.